# Flex 4 - How to format and validate DateField TextInput?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a **DateField** with editable = true. Now i want to validate the DateField TextInput. If the user enter the value like this "200001/12/12", it has to be display the error message. 
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using your own date format, you need to make the validation by your own (custom function). Otherwise, you can use a DateValidator and call validate on DateField change:

```
<mx:DateValidator id="dateValidator" source="{myDate}" property="text" requiredFieldError="You must choose a date" />
<mx:DateField id="myDate" focusOut="dateValidator.validate()" />
```

This is a basic example, maybe you will need to tweak it a little. You can also use the reference (it has a working example at the bottom):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/DateValidator.html

Comment: It's working. I am using formatString like this "YYYY/MM/DD" in my app. If I include this code, it displays the error like "Type the date in the format MM/DD/YYYY". Please share the answer if you know?

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem now? :)